# Foreach in Observable for transformation

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I want to take Item from observable and transform it by `foreach` then result should be saved to new variable.

I'm not sure why this code doesn't work:

```
policYears$: Observable<PolicyYear[]>;
policYearsSelector$: Observable<YearSelector.PolicyYear[]>;

this.policYearsSelector$ = this.policYears$.pipe(
    map((year: YearSelector.PolicyYear[]) => year.forEach(y => y.isActive = this.params.policyYearIds.indexOf(y.id) !== -1))
);
```

I have an error: `Type 'Observable<void>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<PolicyYear[]>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'PolicyYear[]'.`
Why it returns void?

Answer (score 1):

`array.forEach` doesn't return a value as its just used for iterating. So `year.forEach` doesn't return anything to `map` which then returns nothing, thus `void`.

You need to use `year.map` and return a value

Comment: So how exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You are maping data from `policeYears$` and thats of the type "PolicyYears[]"

So you have to change your code to

```
policYears$: Observable<PolicyYear[]>;
policYearsSelector$: Observable<YearSelector.PolicyYear[]>;

this.policYearsSelector$ = this.policYears$.pipe(
    map(
        (year: PolicyYear[]): YearSelector.PolicyYear[] => 
             year.forEach(
                  y => y.isActive = this.params.policyYearIds.indexOf(y.id) !== -1
             )
    )
);
```

year is of the type PolicyYear[] and the map returns a YearSelector.PolicyYear[]

warm regards

Comment: Error: `[ts] Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'PolicyYear[]'`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Array.forEach` returns `void` (thus the error message you're getting because now you're trying to use `map` to map `PolicyYear[]` to `void`).

Now depending on what you want to do you can keep using `forEach` and just return the updated array:

```
map((year: YearSelector.PolicyYear[]) => {
  year.forEach(y => y.isActive = this.params.policyYearIds.indexOf(y.id) !== -1);
  return year;
})
```

Or you can use `Array.map` and return a new array:

```
map((year: YearSelector.PolicyYear[]) => year.map(y => {
  y.isActive = this.params.policyYearIds.indexOf(y.id) !== -1;
  return y;
}))
```